# Create Bounding box for model in XNA 4

Tags: c#, xna

I have the below code which currently creates a bounding box

```
public Wall(Model model, Vector3 position) : base(model){
            this.translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
            Vector3 from = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0f), World);
            Vector3 to = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(1f), World);
            boundingBox = new BoundingBox(from, to);
        }
```

however I end up with the box not at the same position as the model drawn see below (yellow outline is bounding box)

[image]

How do I go about creating the bounding box so that it is in the right position.

I have found:

```
public BoundingBox GetBoundingBoxFromModel(Model model)
        {
            BoundingBox boundingBox = new BoundingBox();


              foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
              {
                VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices =
                  new VertexPositionNormalTexture[mesh.VertexBuffer.SizeInBytes / VertexPositionNormalTexture.SizeInBytes];

                mesh.VertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertices);
                Vector3[] vertexs = new Vector3[vertices.Length];

                for (int index = 0; index < vertexs.Length; index++)
                {
                  vertexs[index] = vertices[index].Position;
                }

                boundingBox = BoundingBox.CreateMerged(boundingBox,
                  BoundingBox.CreateFromPoints(vertexs));
              }

              return boundingBox;
            }
```

But this does not work with XNA 4

How do I go about generating a bounding box for the model that is in the same location as the model drawn.

EDIT

My complete wall class:

```
namespace MapGameLibrary {
    public class Wall : Entity {
        BoundingBox boundingBox;

        public Wall(Model model, Vector3 position) : base(model){
            this.translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
            Vector3 from = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0f), World);
            Vector3 to = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(1f), World);
            boundingBox = new BoundingBox(from, to);
        }

        public BoundingBox GetBoundingBox() {
            return boundingBox;
        }

        public override void Draw(bool textured, Matrix view, Matrix proj)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.World = World * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = proj;
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                }
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the walls are created using:

```
for (int row = 0; row < map.Rows; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < map.Columns; col++)
                {
                    if (map.Get(row, col) == 'w') walls.Add(new Wall(content.Load<Model>("models/wall"), new Vector3(col, 0, row)));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your current method:

The transformations and data used to make the box must be exactly identical to the data and transformations used to render the wall object that the box is used for... EXACTLY the same.

Is the data you use as min & max to make your box, (0 & 1), exactly the same as you would find in the vertex buffer for that wall object (the data used for rendering)?

To build your box, you are transforming 0 & 1  by a matrix called 'World'. Is this the EXACT same matrix that you pass to your effect.World property when rendering the wall section? It is common when rendering in Xna to have a line like `myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo()`. If you have such a line and use its results for rendering then you must also use its results for making a box.

---

your 2nd method: much better.

A vertex buffer is imported into Xna with non-transformed vertex positions (no bone transforms applied). But when rendering, you usually apply bone transforms (via the `CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo()` and using the result in the `effect.World`). So the box you made out of them is a non-transformed box. If you were to transform this box's min & max by the same matrix that makes up your effect.World property, you would be golden.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code used to draw and create the wall objects, hopefully you will be able to spot the issue.